# Make webview first responder when going to fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, first-responder

I have a Mac application allowing the user to use it full screen. When doing that, in the windowDidEnterFullScreen, I try to make my web view first responder but this does not work:

here is my code:

```
- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
 [_webview.window makeFirstResponder:_webview];
}
```

Do you have any idea why it does nothing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the first responder after it enters full screen?  Perhaps a control (like a textfield) in the webview isn't key, so it seems that way?  If you press ESC does it exit full screen?

Comment: Also, what is _webview in this context?  how does it have a `window` property?

Comment: yes it has a valid window property, and nothing happens if I press ESC

Comment: er sorry, what type of class is `_webview`?

Comment: this is a regular Mac cocoa web view

Comment: what SDK are you building against?  I only see `hostWindow` available in the API